# Allign all the elements on the left CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a table with this

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Network Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Abbreviated
                </th>
                <th>
                    Description
                </th>
                <th>
                    Has Channel
                </th>

                <th>
                    IsActive
                </th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

The output I am getting is like this

[image]

I want each of them to be alligned left.

How to do it?

Comment: Can you show us the styles for classes `table table-striped table-bordered table-hover` or styles related to showing this `table` structure.

Comment: @Sinto there are many css files I don't know which one has it's info or even it has one

Comment: are you using bootstrap??

Comment: @Ylama yes bootstrap.css is also there along with many others

Comment: @c.k thats just bad advice man... using `!important` is not the solution. just target the specific table.

Comment: is the output provided is valid

Comment: table heading are defined in a table row know..then why they are displayed in seperate lines

Comment: In your browser, right-click one of the table header texts (i.e. “Network name“), click `Inspect element`. In the newly opened Developer Tools, check the “Properties“ window and check which rule applies `text-align: right;`. You will need to overwrite that rule in your CSS, i.e. by being more specific than the existing rule or by adding the same rule after the existing rule definition.

Comment: @SaschaM78 Inside Properties, I have many things
1)label.col-sm4.control-label 2) Html Label Element 3) HTML element 4)Element 5)Node 6) Event Target 7)object ... which one to see?

Comment: @SaschaM78 Please tell

Comment: I added an answer, see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your browser, right-click one of the table header texts (i.e. “Network name“), click **"Inspect element"**. In the newly opened Developer Tools, click the “*Styles*“ window.

In the "Styles" tab you can find all rules that are applied to the selected element. One of these rules will contain said `text-align: right;`. That's the rule that you want to overwrite, i.e. by being more specific than the mentioned rule.

**Example**

you have a general rule for the table header as in your mentioned case.

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table tr th {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Row header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row data</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Being more specific can be achieved by using an `ID` or `class`, I'll use a class in my example:

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

/* existing rule just for illustration */
table tr th {
  text-align: right;
}

/* more specific than above rule */
table.left-header tr th {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="left-header">
  <tr>
    <th>Row header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row data</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your code is working and your bootstrap `css` is working.. then it should be in one line aligned left but in your case if not Bootstrap has a class that could do it : `class="text-left"`

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover pull-left">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left">
                    Network Name
                </th>
                <th class="text-left">
                    Abbreviated
                </th>
                <th class="text-right">
                    Description
                </th>
                <th class="text-left">
                    Has Channel
                </th>

                <th class="text-left">
                    IsActive
                </th>
                <th class="text-left">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

i would not prefer adding the class to each `th` but its a solution since you dont really provide code to work with.

**Description** is aligned right just to give you an idea of whats happening. just by adding classes using bootstrap.

Answer (score -1):

```
text-align: left;
```

This property is used for aligning text left. Kindly inspect and find the class which has `text-align: right;` and change it.

Comment: `table tr th {
    text-align: left;
}`

Comment: Kindly provide more details if my answer didn't help you out instead of down voting. Thanks

Comment: @Ylama where should I put it?

Comment: in your css file. But right way to do is to debug and change already written property for it i.e., text-align: right to left

Comment: look i did not down vote this because its a valid awnser if you ask me. Inspect, find the css that ads the align right, and overwrite..and yess in your css file, but if you dont know how to , just look at my awnser and add the class to the `th` wil help

Comment: I know @Ylama that you didn't. You did right thing to add comment to add it to my post

Comment: Also if these are labels in table then consider changing <th> tag to <td> @Breathing

Answer (score -1):

You can add a class to `th` element then style the class:

`<th class="align-to-left">`

```
.align-to-left{
      text-align:left;
    }
```

Comment: `!important` should always be the last resort as it can't be overwritten again by another rule. Always try to be more specific than an existing rule, that leaves others the option to overwrite your rule if it is required.